# Telegram API asnwer poll

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

I want to get result of belwo poll using @bot.poll_answer_handler()

```
import telebot
from telebot import types,util

API_TOKEN = 'token'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(regexp="work")
def send_poll(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_poll(message.chat.id, question='When do you prefer to work?', options=['Morning', 'Night'])


bot.infinity_polling()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.poll_answer_handler()
def handle_poll_answer(poll_answer):
    print(f'{poll_answer.option_ids}')
```

It will print the chosen option by its number. [0] for 'Morning', [1] for 'Night'